# Adding dynamic header/footer to Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm wondering if there is a way to add dynamic headers or footers to a document, i.e. putting a "Page Title" in the footer that is different for every page.

I understand that editing the built-in header or footer would be reflected on every page. I'm wondering if anyone has thought of a workaround to either "force" it by accessing the first/last line on a page and inserting text there, or if there is another way to dynamically update the page.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is not yet available. There is an open [issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4887) on can't reliably access first page vs other pages header / footer info.

I've used the codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37529583/5995040), to list the  document's children.

```
DocumentBodySection: Index 0
HeaderSection: Index 1
FooterSection: Index 2
HeaderSection: Index 3
FooterSection: Index 4
```

This function change the text of the selected child.

```
function myFunction() {
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var footer = copyDoc.getFooter();
  Logger.log(footer.getParent().getChild(2).asText().setText("Test"))
}
```

Second Page
[image]

Third Page
[image]

Changing a footer section will apply to all footer section, according to this [blog](http://Headers%20and%20Footers%20-%20the%20way%20you%20want%20them) you can only set a different header/footer in the first page. The provided open issue link also states that it can only be checked manually as it is not available.