# Google App Script | Headers and Footers | Replace text

Tags: google-apps-script, footer, google-docs

I'm trying to built a script that replace some Data in a Google Document.
I'm just observing a problem. The script works well for all the body and the footers from the 2nd to the last page.
My first page footer is set as different than the others but i couldn't find a way to modify its content.

Do you have any solutions ?
By the way, I'm looking for a way to open the new document in my browser at the end of the script. Any solutions too ?
There's a part of my script.

```
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById('1mh8yjFpy7NcjB8meXWvn1SKQofjSMcFdPqWBe4GoC14').makeCopy().getId();
  var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
  var footer = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getFooter();
  DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName('RM_' + RM + '_' + IDEtude + "_" + Prenom + "_" + Nom);
  
  footer.replaceText("{RM_REF}", RM);
  footer.replaceText("{PROJECT_REF}", IDEtude);

  body.replaceText("{RM_REF}", RM);
  body.replaceText("{PROJECT_REF}", IDEtude);
  body.replaceText("{NumeroBA}", numBA);
  body.replaceText('{PrenomNom}', Prenom + " " +Nom);
  body.replaceText('{adresse}', Adresse);
  body.replaceText('{code postal et ville}', CP);
  body.replaceText('{numero de telephone}', NumTel);
  body.replaceText('{CLIENT_COMPANY}', NomClient);
  body.replaceText('{DatedeFin}', DatedeFin);
  body.replaceText('{DatedeDebut}', DatedeDebut);
  body.replaceText('{FaitLe}',Date);
  body.replaceText('{Ville}',VilleCdP);
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: As for open new document. As far as I know Google App Script has the limitation, it can't do it. It can create and modify new document, but you should open the doc manually if you want to see it in a browser.

Comment: Ok thanks, and do you have any solutions for my footer issue ?

Comment: I had to deal only with Google Spreadsheets. I never had to make scripts for Google Documents. I could try to look what could be done there if you show me your doc file. Your sample looks fine but it doesn't tell me much about how exactly your footers look like. And this hellish heap of variables, where they came from?

Comment: There's an open link for my docs https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iXolBrL3pZlv3X9z0sVxderumb5qOEJE1I1Kr7Qk-8o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I use a spreadsheet to get the data but the problem isn't comming from the variables (the replace function works for all the document but the first page footer).

Comment: And there is an exemple of a generated document : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VOq9e_VTqojM4_4zFxULIqkSWGaPIeV2BcOtBlorPTQ/edit?usp=sharing Thanks for your help !

Comment: It looks like there IS the way to open any Google Document (any link?) in a browser from GAS. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174330 I didn't try it, but probably I will try it soon, since this is a rather important option for many cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add these three lines in your `Code.gs` after the line 37:

```
first_footer = footer.getParent().getChild(3);
first_footer.replaceText("{RM_REF}", RM);
first_footer.replaceText("{PROJECT_REF}", IDEtude);
```

`...getParent().getChild(3)` — is the hack to get access to a footer on a 'different first page' (probably it's your case)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877330/how-to-get-multiple-headers-footers-in-a-document-with-google-apps-script

Answer (score 0):

I decided to add the very important part about **How to open a new Document (or any document) from GAS in new tab**. Here is the way.

At the end of your main function `GenererRM()` you need to add this:

```
redirect('https://docs.google.com/document/d/' + documentId);
```

It calls the function `redirect()` with the ID of your new document. The function is below (it's need to add in your script as one more function):

```
function redirect(SSurl) {
  let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('redirect.html');
  html.SSurl = SSurl; 
  var htmlOutput = html.evaluate();    
  DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput,'Bon voyage!');
}
```

Then you'll need to make the new file `redirect.html` along with your `Code.gs`.

[image]

Here is a content of this file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>     
      var SSurl = <?= SSurl ?> ;
      window.open(SSurl,"_blank");
      google.script.host.close();
    </script>
  </body>
<html>
```

It's all. Now your new created document will be open in a new tab automatically every time when the function `redirect()` is called.

Credits: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1174330