# Why doesn't my footer.replaceText(searchPattern, replacement) function work?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm attempting to autofill a google doc from a google form submission. I am able to autofill the search patterns in my google doc body but can't get the same thing to happen in the footer.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function autofillGoogleDocFromForm(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var clientName = e.values[1]
  var description = e.values[2];
  var deposit = e.values[3];
  var deadlineDate = e.values[4];
  var contractDate = e.values[5];
  
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("1zZ7Whalwool9qnuWpdzwA_XxCykoBF2h3bSJYgWZtSg");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1zVPg9q1cfV_UFAZ3QGn_FdWnaiD8d9wH");
  
  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(clientName + ', '+ contractDate, templateResponseFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText('{{ClientName}}', clientName);
  body.replaceText('{{ClientName1}}', clientName);
  body.replaceText('{{Description}}', description);
  body.replaceText('{{Deposit}}', deposit);
  body.replaceText('{{DeadlineDate}}', deadlineDate);
  
  var footer = doc.getFooter();
  footer.replaceText("{{ClientName2}}", clientName);
  footer.replaceText("{{CurrentDate}}", contractDate);
  
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: Must be something wrong with your patterns.  Are you sure that you don't have to escape the `{}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64511948/google-app-script-headers-and-footers-replace-text

Comment: @TheMaster unfortunately not! My footers are the same on every page. This code works when I choose "different first page" but then the rest of my footer search patterns don't get replaced.

Comment: @Cooper I'm not sure what you mean by "escape the {}" . My search patterns work for the body so I'm not sure what is going differently in the footer.

Comment: Hi ! I tried to reproduce your script editing the footer but I could not reproduce it as in my environment it worked correctly. What does it happen when you run the function? Does your footer change in any way? Do you get any error message? Also, could you please log ```clientName``` and ```contractDate``` before you replace the footer to make sure they are not empty arrays? Btw i assume your footer contains the following strings: ```{{}ClientName2}} {{CurrentDate}}```. If you also could provide a sample (with no sensitive data) of how the footer looks like it would be great :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf, I made a censored copy of my google doc for you to look at: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QN5HQz5Wut6v6BYrPxmLQRV6jUXyh7kE4ieXtdnSxxk/edit?usp=sharing.

When I run the function, every search pattern in the body of my document is replaced correctly. My footer search patterns are not replaced at all, and I get no error message. 

I'm not sure what you mean by "log clientName and contractDate before you replace the footer" (sorry I'm very new to this!).

Comment: So I was able to reproduce with the document you shared. Strangely enough I copied all the information of the document to a new document I created including the footer and page count and the function worked correctly. I also tested changing your text to a simple string like ```aa``` to see if it was a regular expression error and it was still happening. **Could you detail me as much as you can the reproduction steps that you took to create this document (i.e added the text, then the footer, then the page count through the menu bar, etc)?**

Comment: @MateoRandwolf Thank you so much for your help. Because you kept saying it was working on your end, I decided to just create a brand new document from scratch--and it worked! My previous contract was copy and pasted from a word document (which I guess caused some problems).

Comment: Was this Word document imported into Google Sheets or did you just copy paste the information from it (including the footer) into the Google Document?