# footer.replaceText() does not replace my placeholder with new text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Can anyone explain why `footer.replaceText()` does not replace my placeholder with new text. It works for both header and body.

```
//opens the master report document which is now saved as the student's name and gets the contents of the header
let header = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getHeader()

    //opens the master report document which is now saved as the student's name and gets the contents of the body
    let body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody()
    
//opens the master report document which is now saved as the student's name and gets the contents of the footer
let footer = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getFooter()

header.replaceText('{{First Name}}', row[studentDetails.firstName])
body.replaceText('{{Maths Attainment}}', row[studentDetails.mathsAttainment])
footer.replaceText('{{Class Teacher}}', row[studentDetails.classTeacher])
```

I can't seem to find an answer on Stack Overflow that works.

Comment: Could be an issue with your place holder. Check to make sure its actually`{{Class Teacher}}` in your Google Doc. If not that then check your row payload and ensure that `studentDetails.classTeacher` returns the expected row index.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot, thank you for your suggestion. I have checked closely. When I change footer to body, it replaces the {{Class Teacher}} as it should. It is only when it says footer that it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Currently we can not reproduce the problem with your code.  So we cannot help you.

Comment: So, did you get an answer after all? It's not exactly a good thing to ask questions, get answers, and disappear without any feedback. To say the least.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately your suggestion didn’t solve the solution. I had read about that particular answer, but the ‘Use a different header’ option is unchecked. I am still trying to work out why and will provide a reproducible piece of code shortly. Again thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the option 'Different first page' you can't get the footer and header of the first page in the common (documented) way.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877330/how-to-get-multiple-headers-footers-in-a-document-with-google-apps-script) try to get them this 'secret' way:

```
let first_header = header.getParent().getChild(3);
let first_footer = header.getParent().getChild(4);
```

And then you can change them as usual:

```
first_header.replaceText('{{First Name}}', row[studentDetails.firstName]);
first_footer.replaceText('{{Class Teacher}}', row[studentDetails.classTeacher]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give credit to Mr. Amit Agarwal who has provided a working solution to above.

The code is below:

```
const replaceHeaderFooter = () => {
  // Returns the document with the specified ID
  const doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT ID');

  // Retrieves the headers's container element which is DOCUMENT
  const parent = doc.getHeader().getParent();

  for (let i = 0; i < parent.getNumChildren(); i += 1) {
    // Retrieves the child element at the specified child index
    const child = parent.getChild(i);

    // Determine the exact type of a given child element
    const childType = child.getType();

    if (childType === DocumentApp.ElementType.HEADER_SECTION) {
      // Replaces all occurrences of a given text in regex pattern
      child.asHeaderSection().replaceText('{{Company}}', 'Digital Inspiration');
    } else if (childType === DocumentApp.ElementType.FOOTER_SECTION) {
      // Replaces all occurrences of a given text in regex pattern
      child.asFooterSection().replaceText('{{Copyright}}', '© Amit Agarwal');
    }
  }

  // Saves the current Document.
  // Causes pending updates to be flushed and applied.
  doc.saveAndClose();
};
```

Thank you!